# Create new array with only the duplicate items in Javascript using for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a function to find all the elements that appear more than  once in the array and then return those elements in an array. **Example: Input: [2,7,4,10,12,27,4,7,7,12, 10] Output: [4,7,10,12]**

This is what i have so far:

```
let arr= [4,4,6,8,8,9,10,10]

var method1 = function(a) {
  var counts = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
        for(var j = i; j <= a.length; j++) {
            if(i != j && a[i] == a[j]) {
                counts.push(a[i]);
                }
              }
            }

    return counts;
}
console.log(method1(arr));
```

It works when the array only have two of a number, but not if there are more. How can I  push to counts only one of each number independently of how many duplicates there are?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all non-unique values (i.e.: duplicate/more than one occurrence) in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/get-all-non-unique-values-i-e-duplicate-more-than-one-occurrence-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a hash table for counting the values and if you have a count of two, take this element.

```js
var array = [2, 7, 4, 10, 12, 27, 4, 7, 7, 12, 10],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = array.filter(v => (hash[v] = (hash[v] || 0) + 1) === 2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: nice technique! so why not an empty object `{}` literal instead of `Object.create(null)`?

Comment: it generates an empty object without prototypes, like `toString`.

Answer (score 1):

You use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and compare [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) of element to check if occurs more than once

```js
const method1 = (arr) => [...new Set(arr.filter(elm => arr.indexOf(elm) !== arr.lastIndexOf(elm)))]
console.log(method1([2,7,4,10,12,27,4,7,7,12, 10]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a marker that would signal that item was already seen. It can be done with a dictionary

```js
let arr= [4,4,6,8,8,9,10,10];

function solution(arr) {
  const marker = {};
  const duplicates = []
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (marker[item]) {
      duplicates.push(item);
    } else {
      marker[item] = true;
    }
  }
  return duplicates;
}

const s = solution(arr);
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> ***Here the idea is :-***

- We initialize `op` with two keys `unique` and `repeated`.
- whenever any digit appear for the first time we initialize `unique` with that digit as key value pair. now when the same digit appear again we set `repeated` property with that digit as key value pair.
- In the end we take values out of `repeated` key

```js
let arr = [2,7,4,10,12,27,4,7,7,12, 10]

let op = arr.reduce((op, inp) => {
  if(op.unique[inp] !== undefined){
    op.repeated[inp] = inp
  } else{
    op.unique[inp] = inp
  }
  return op
},{unique:{},repeated:{}})

console.log(Object.values(op.repeated))
```